# How to add global style in sharepoint framework(SPFx)?

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, sharepointframework

I am looking for a option to hide the header globally. So, is there any way to add styles globally in sharepoint framework.

Note: Opted Reactjs to build we parts.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [Application Customizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension) to hide the element for modern view globally.

[Use jQuery in SPFx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/add-jqueryui-accordion-to-web-part)

My test result.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
                  $("span:contains('Office 365')").css('display','none');
                })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would inject a custom CSS stylesheet using an application customerizer.

Here the code to inject your custom CSS:
https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss

Here is an article I wrote that explains how to do it:
https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/

The article explains why you should be careful with such customizations.

Let me know if you need help with the CSS.